# Anime with a fox girl and another girl fighting

Tags: story-identification, anime

I remember this fox girl, or cat girl I'm not sure shows up from the past. She has magical creatures that are like flying cats that have spiky tails and her and some other girl are fighting over the protagonist.

There's a scene where one girl is unzipping her body suit. I know it sounds crazy, but please help me find this!! I've looked everywhere its almost as if this anime doesn't exist

Comment: If the anime is Japanese, it's possible that the fox/cat is a [kitsune](http://www.mythicalcreaturesguide.com/page/Kitsune) (legendary Japanese foxes with nine tails). It might be of help when researching this anime. Here is [a list of some kistunes in animes](https://honeysanime.com/top-10-anime-kitsune-girl-fox-girl/), maybe yours is in it :)

Comment: Can you provide any more information? Can you remember what year you saw it? Or at least which decade? What sort of genre was it?

Comment: Based on the anime that I have watched, I only remember *Asobi ni Iku yo!* having a cat girl (looks like a fox girl?) wearing a bodysuit in a harem situation.

Comment: Could it be [Tenchi_Muyo!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenchi_Muyo!_Ryo-Ohki)

Answer (score -1):

could it be the girl who cried fox? i’ve been trying to find something like you described too

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by [edit]ing it to explain why you think this might be the correct anime, i.e. the ways in which it matches the one described in the question. It would help the rest of us to decide how likely this answer is to be correct, and whether we should therefore upvote it or not.